# why won't jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css apply to _Layout.mobile.cshtml?

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile, razor

I've being following the this tutorial ,www.youtube.com/watch?v=5HpyqG0pK4Q.
On creating mobile views within MVC 4 application.
I've followed all as per the video, but cannot get the Index.phone.cshtml view to use the _Layout.phone.cshtml.
Is it because I'm using VS2010 instead of vs 2012 ?
Or because it's a older version of jquery mobile ?
I had to manually add the jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css.
Or is there an obvious answer that I'm not seeing ?

My Global.asax.cs file-

```
     public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        IntializeBundles();
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();


        IntializeDisplayModeProviders();
    }

    protected void IntializeBundles()
    {
        var phoneScripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MobileJS")
        .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery 1.*");

        var phoneStyles = new StyleBundle("~/bundles/MobileCSS")
            .Include("~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css",
                    "~/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css",
                    "~/Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css");

        BundleTable.Bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(phoneScripts);
        BundleTable.Bundles.Add(phoneStyles);

    }

    protected void IntializeDisplayModeProviders()
    {
        var phone = new DefaultDisplayMode("Phone")
        {
            ContextCondition = ctx => ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent() != null && ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent().Contains("iPhone")
        };

        var tablet = new DefaultDisplayMode("Tablet")
        {
            ContextCondition = ctx => ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent() != null && ctx.GetOverriddenUserAgent().Contains("iPad")
        };

        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, phone);
        DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(1, tablet);
    }
}
```

}

My _Layout.phone.cshtml-

```
   <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

     @Styles.Render("~/bundles/MobileCSS")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/MobileJS")

</head>
```

My Index.phone.cshtml-

```
  @{
ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
Layout = "../Shared/_Layout.Phone.cshtml";
 }
    <h1>This is a phone</h1>
```

Comment: remove `jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css` and place `jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css` before `jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css`.

Comment: are you loading jQuery (core) before jQuery-Mobile?

Comment: no, should I be ??  var phoneScripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MobileJS")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.*",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*");

Comment: jQuery (core JS) should be loaded before jQM (JS) as it's dependent.

Comment: ok switched to the following, cleaned, rebuilt , cleared history...and still the same result.    var phoneScripts = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/MobileJS")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-1.*",
                     "~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.*");